# Phone Number Length Validation in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
[Integer]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number")]
public int Phone { get; set; }
```

I want to add Phone Number Length Validation, How can i add this.

If I use `[MaxLength(10)]` 
Than it shows Error!!!!

Comment: you should use data type string

Comment: phone numbers are not numbers.  they can consist of spaces, brackets, plus symbols to represent international dial code, dashes, all sorts of things.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store phone number as string, so I can type ie,. +447912345678 or 00447912345678.

Than you can use `StringLength` attribute.

Remember that users might type the number with spaces or hyphons, ie. 079 12 34 56 78, or 079-12-34-56-78.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use a string for the phone number field. Obviosuly if it is not a mandatory business request.

Then you can apply the [StringLengthAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use phone number as string and use `MaxLength` to validate.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your phone number")]
[MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage="Cannot be longer than 10 characters")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```